# how to update terminal values in realtime

Tags: ruby

I have the following asc table:

```
+---------------------------------------------+
|                    Report                   |
+----------+----------+-------------+---------+
| Store    | Total                            |
+----------+----------+-------------+---------+
| A        | 2723                             |
| B        | 7277                             |
+----------+----------+-------------+---------+
```

I need to update the total while threre are updates running on my database.
How can I do that?
I already have the method that gets updated total.
But how can I persist the total on the terminal screen?

Comment: The simple solution is to just print the whole table again with the updated values. If you're wanting to edit existing data already displayed on the terminal, I would look at something like ncurses: https://github.com/ruby/curses

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the following gems

- https://github.com/ruby/curses
- https://github.com/tj/terminal-table

Example :

```
require 'terminal-table'
require "curses"

Curses.init_screen
Curses.crmode
Curses.noecho
Curses.stdscr.keypad = true

begin
  x = 0
  y = 0

  loop do
  
    table = Terminal::Table.new do |t|
      t << ['Random 1', Random.rand(1...10)]
      t.add_row ['Random 1', Random.rand(10...100)]
    end 
  
    Curses.setpos(x, y)
    output = table.render.to_s 
    Curses.addstr(output)
    Curses.refresh
    sleep 1
  end
ensure
  close_screen
end
```